# How to compare two dates created as JodaTime LocalDate and LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, jodatime

```
LocalDate startDate = new LocalDate(2014,1,2);

LocalDateTime startDateTime = new LocalDateTime(2014,1,2,14,0);
```

I need to compare `startDate` and `startDateTime` with respect to the date, something like this:

```
// boolean equalDates = startDate.isequal(startDateTime.getDate());
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want to compare the date part, you can do it like so:

```
LocalDate startDate = new LocalDate(2014, 1, 2);
LocalDateTime startDateTime = new LocalDateTime(2014, 1, 2, 14, 0);
LocalDate forCompare = startDateTime.toLocalDate();
System.out.println("equal dates: " + forCompare.equals(startDate));
// equal dates: true
```

[docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html#toLocalDate%28%29)

Comment: Keep in mind that `equals()` also compares the underlying chronologies and not just the field values, else the given solution is fine. Best is only to use ISOChronology.

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal See my updated code. And yes, I have tested it using Joda-Time v2.8.1. Maybe you have used other libraries with same class names ??? Check your imports.

Answer (score 4):

```
LocalDate startDate = new LocalDate(2014,1,2);

LocalDateTime startDateTime = new LocalDateTime(2014,1,2,00,0);

System.out.println(startDate.toDate());
System.out.println(startDateTime.toDate());


if(startDate.toDate().compareTo((startDateTime.toDate()))==0){
 System.out.println("equal");       
}
```

the output will be:

Thu Jan 02 00:00:00 IST 2014

Thu Jan 02 00:00:00 IST 2014

equal

Comment: Any reasonable implementation of `equals` for a case like this would probably do the equality comparison with 0 inside of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if say one date is in between another time frame, say is `date1` 4hrs in between `date2`, joda has different classes just for those scenarios you can use:

```
Hours h = Hours.hoursBetween(date1, date2);
Days s = Days.daysBetween(date1, date2);
Months m = Months.monthsBetween(date1,date2);
```

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseSingleFieldPeriod.html