# Android comparing current date to date in parse for query

Tags: java, android, date, parse-platform

I am attempting to compare the current date and time with a date and time in parse. I would like the query to only return the events that have not closed for their registering period which would be their "end" date. But for some reason my parameters are not working the code is the following:

```
String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());// gets current date and time


    query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("end", currentDateTimeString);// should compare the dates and if the end date is past the current moment and time of this query not display that event
```

Comment: Please clarify the problem you are actually experiencing.  What message or incorrect behavior is happening? Where is the actual comparison taking place that is failing?  Show that code and debug or log information indicating the failure.  What you show above simply adds a constraint to your `ParseQuery` object.  Where do you actually evaluate the result of the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use Date indeed if a String. the Parse Date Col. are comparable to Date.

```
query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("end", new Date());
```

Comment: so this one just takes the current date?

Comment: yes new Date() always returns the current date + time

Answer (score 1):

You can use Joda Time library. [See the example below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376022/how-to-compare-two-dates-created-as-jodatime-localdate-and-localdatetime)

```
LocalDate startDate = new LocalDate(2014, 1, 2);
LocalDateTime startDateTime = new LocalDateTime(2014, 1, 2, 14, 0);
LocalDate forCompare = startDateTime.toLocalDate();
System.out.println("equal dates: " + forCompare.equals(startDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Send the DateChecker function a date and if that date is before the the current date return true. If it is not return false.

```
public bool DateChecker(DateTime dt){
    if(DateTime.Now.Day<=dt.Day && DateTime.Now.Month<=dt.Month && DateTime.Now.Year<=dt.Year)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
//BELOW CODE GOES IN A DIFFERENT FUNCTION
DateTime? dt;
var yourQuery = ParseObject.GetQuery ("YourClass");
yourQuery.FindAsync ().ContinueWith (task => {
if(!task.IsCompleted){
    return;
}
if(task.IsCompleted){
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = task.Result;
    foreach(ParseObject result in results){
        string oid = "";
        if(result.ObjectId!=null){
            oid = result.ObjectId;
        }else{
            oid = "1337";
        }
        dt = result.("YourDateColumn in parse");
        DateTime tmpDate;
        tmpDate = dt ?? DateTime.Now;
        if (tmpDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && tmpDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && DateChecker (tmpDate)) {
            //adds items for this time period only
        }
    }
}
```

});